# Django template input button post problem

Tags: django, templates, post, button, input

I try to post value of input buttons in Django but I couldn't
This is my template

```
<form id="ReviewRateForm" method="post" action="/review/post/rate/">
      <input type="button" hint="V1" title="V" value="1" id="radio{{ forloop.counter }}-1" type="button" name="qid[{{forloop.counter}}]"></input>
      <input type="button" hint="V1" title="V" value="2" id="radio{{ forloop.counter }}-1" type="button" name="qid[{{forloop.counter}}]"></input>
      <input type="button" hint="V1" title="V" value="1" id="radio{{ forloop.counter }}-1" type="button" name="qid[{{forloop.counter}}]"></input>
</form>
```

However, when I debug it I couldn't reach the values of that input buttons in my view.

What is the problem or how can I overcome it?

Comment: How are you trying to access the values in your view? Have you trying accessing [`request.POST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST)?

Comment: ... and, why are you using `{{ forloop.counter }}` outside a `for` block? And if you do have a `for` block wrapping the pasted code, you'll end up with all 3 inputs with the same `name` and `id`. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Shawn - I agree. I'm not sure what the o.p. is trying to do here.

Comment: Why don't you repost this question in terms of the problem that you are trying to solve, rather than in terms of how to make your implementation (which will never work very well) work.

Comment: @Jordan I will definetely do that. I am sorry guys I had a terrible toothache while I was writing that post and now I see that it has bad explantation. Sorry..

Answer (score 0):

The values can be accessed by the name of the input from request.POST. However, you're dynamically naming the inputs, which is going to make things more complicated when you go to retrieve those values.

Example without taking into consideration the dynamic naming:

```
quid1 = request.POST.get('quid1')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with your browser rather than with django.

If you use the button element in an HTML form, different browsers will submit different values. Internet Explorer will submit the text between the `<button>` and `</button>` tags, while other browsers will submit the content of the value attribute.

Update: Oh, you are not using `<button>` elements, I read too fast.  Sorry.  Then this answer is not relevant.